# Fatal error when try to create a user role

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, user-roles

When I try to create a new user role from admin , it is throwing an error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Amlocator_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/vhosts/stand-out.net/httpdocs/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May there are issue in any third partly extension.

Basically  `adminhtml.xml`  define the `acl permission for a module`.

On this xml there some code written like `module="amlocator"` .where amlocator is helper prefix.

**Example of helper : Module Mage_Catalog**

```
<global>
....
<helpers>
<catalog><!-- call as helper prefix or identifier of catalog modules  -->
<class>Mage_Catalog_Helper</class>
</catalog>
</helpers>
.....
```

Whenevet `module="amlocator"` emulated then it call class a  `basic helper` (`NameSpace_Module_Helper_Data)` of module which in `register in config.xml`.

In you instace ,the system **does not find any helper class of this helper  idendtifier(amlocator)**.

**As  per as magento mechanism** , magento make `Core NameSpace(Mage ->app/code/Core/Mage)` module helper class `Mage_Amlocator_Helper_Data` if it not find any code pool (community,local,Mage)
.
But that does not exits n system .That why create issue

### Solution:

- May be define helper class properly but Typo issue  on  `amlocator` in `adminhtml.xml`
- Or You have `a custom  module` which has `system.xml and
  adminhtml.xml` but `Helper class does not define at config.xml.

`

```
<global>
....
<helpers>
<amlocator><!-- call as helper prefix or identifier of catalog modules  -->
<class>NameSpace_ModuleName_Helper</class>
</amlocator>
</helpers>
.....
```

And class `app/code/MOduleCodePool/NameSpace/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Helper_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Comment: yes I have created an empty module for amlocator and added the helper there it solved the issue thanks

Answer (score 3):

That means, you either have

1. an explicit call to `Mage::helper('amlocator')` somewhere but the "amlocator" module does not exist or does not define a helper namespace, or
2. try to translate something within the scope of the "amlocator" module, but this module does not define a helper namespace

Comment: is this a custom module or magento inbuilt module ?

Comment: It's a custom module, probably something by @Amasty

Comment: well there is no such a module , I have checked each directory

Comment: Then you should search for "amlocator" in `app` and see if you find any leftovers.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the adminhtml.xml File from the autoshipping extension. Found here: app/code/local/Amasty/Autoshipping/etc/adminhtml.xml

Commented this part out of the file:

```
<amautoshipping translate="title" module="amlocator">
    <title>Default Shipping Method</title>
</amautoshipping>
```

Afterwards it was working again to set group rules for users over the admin panel. But I dont know, if Autoshipping is still working (not using it).